# Creating a sql sequence

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
CREATE SEQUENCE HIBERNATE_SEQUENCE    
INCREMENT BY 1
START WITH 32137148  
MAXVALUE 1E28  
MINVALUE 1  
NOCYCLE  
CACHE 20  
NOORDER
```

can anyone take a look at this sql and tell me with you can find a problem next to NOCYCLE

I'm using PostgreSQL

Comment: What rdbms are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using what seems to be Oracle syntax.

Since you're using PostgreSQL, you should double-check the syntax here: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createsequence.html

For example, `NOCYCLE` should be `NO CYCLE`, and `NOORDER` isn't supported at all.

It pays to read the documentation for the product you're using!

Comment: oh thanks you're right, i'm using an oracle syntax as a template but i didn't know about the noorder.

Answer (score 0):

As @Bill wrote, Oracle syntax doesn't work for Postgres. Best match in Postgres would be:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE hibernate_sequence
START 32137148  
CACHE 20
```

Which is the short for:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE hibernate_sequence
INCREMENT 1
MINVALUE 1
MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807  -- maximum possible
START 32137148  
CACHE 20
NO CYCLE
```

- There is no `NOORDER` option.
- `MAXVALUE 1E28` .. invalid number format and outside the range of Postgres' `bigint` implementation.

Other options translated. [All in the manual.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createsequence.html)